# How to show the content on ajax or Jquery lightbox

Tags: ajax, javascript, theming

I have created views custom template file for one of my view and works fine. And how can i show fields content(second in the below code) on Lightbox popup box when the user clicks on title field.

```
 <?php dpm($fields); ?> <div id="cusom-template-flower-fields"
 class="title">   <?php print $fields["title"]->content; ?> </div> <div
 id="cusom-template-flower-field_availability"
 class="field_availability">   <?php print
 $fields["field_availability"]->content; ?> </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should describe the problem you are facing ... 
What 'lightbox-meme' are you trying to implement ?

If you are using the [lightbox module for drupal](http://drupal.org/project/lightbox2), you should read the README.txt, that is pretty self-explanatory.

Hope this helps.